# Azure Bot Builder get telegramID from telegram UserName

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, bots, telegram

I am creating a telegram bot that trackers users in a group based on their telegram ID, the unique number.

I want to do a command using the azure bot builder that when i type /ShowUserActivityByUserName @[UserName], I will get the telegram ID from the username and pull out all the data from my database that have this telegram ID

Is there anyway I can query telegram and get the userID?

I am using the base template from azure bot maker

```
public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
{
    var message = await argument;

    if (message.Text.StartsWith("/"))
    {
        if (message.Text.StartsWith("/ShowUserActivityByUserName "))
        {
            // do database things
            string userID = getTelegramIDFromUserName(getStringAfter(message.Text, "/ShowUserActivityByUserName "));
            await context.PostAsync("UserID: " + username);
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
}

public string getTelegramIDFromUserName(string username)
{
    return username;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to store messages from the users of your bot in a table utilizing their usernames and userIDs. This will be easier than making a second call to find the ID number, especially since telegram allows multiples of the same username. These are sent with each message, but telegram also does not include an endpoint to differentiate between "clashing" names in the same chat.

Here's an implementation that echoes the telegram userID and first name in a return message. The key here is getting the ID itself from the message, which is done using

```
message.ChannelData.message.from.id
```

and

```
message.ChannelData.message.from.first_name
```

These fields are included in all messages sent to your bot from telegram. You can use these where ever you have access to the message to store the userID or make calls utilizing it.

The full method looks like the following:

```
public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            var message = await argument;

            if (message.ChannelId == "telegram")
            {
                await context.PostAsync($"Your userid is {message.ChannelData.message.from.id} and your name is {message.ChannelData.message.from.first_name}");
            }
            else { 
                await context.PostAsync($"You said {message.Text}"); //non-telegram stuff
            }
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        }
```

The if check for telegram isn't necessarily the best way to separate channel functionality, but it's there to represent this being telegram-only code. You can find more information on what the telegram API includes in calls to your bot [here.](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#available-types)